# Is $(\lVert x \rVert - \lVert y \rVert)^2$ convex?

Tags: normed-spaces, convex-analysis

I am trying to figure out if $f: \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^{2n} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ with
$$f(x,y)= (\lVert x \rVert - \lVert y \rVert)^2$$
is a convex function.
I would be interested if it is the case for any p-Norm, but only one of them like the eucledian norm would also be helpful.

So far I have tried:

- Using the definition of convexity, but I was not able to find estimations that led to the desired inequality
- Checking if the Hessian is positive semidefinite for n=2 via the eigenvalues. I was not able to estimate if they are non-negative.
- Trying to show $f(x,y) \geq f(a,b)+ \nabla f(a,b)^T ((x,y)-(a,b))$. Again, I was not able to find an expedient estimation
- for n=1 the problem reduces to $(|x|-|y|)^2$, which is convex on $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^{2}$ (the Hessian has eigenvalues $0$ and $4$).

The question is how to come to an solution for the n-dimensional case?

Comment: Your notation is a bit peculiar. In the expression $f(x,y)$, is your intention that $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^n_{\ge 0} \times \mathbb R^n_{\ge 0} \approx \mathbb R^{2n}_{\ge 0}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A counterexample for $n=2$: With $a = (2, 0)$ and $b = (0, 2)$ is
$$
 f(a, a)  = f(b, a) = 0 
$$
but
$$
 f(\frac{a+b}{2}, a) > 0 \, .
$$
This can be generalized to all dimensions $n \ge 2$ by appending zeros to the components of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: yeah was just gonna write this. That $f$ vanishes as long as $x,y$ have same length is immediate red flag.